# Is it possible to allow external programs to break up the Electron sub-processes into their own process?

Tags: electron

I'm developing an electron application for Wallpaper Engine, a program meant to allow dynamic wallpapers. Normally, Wallpaper Engine is simply used for things like normal web backgrounds (without any form of file system support) and video backgrounds, however it does have support for exe applications. While I'm not 100% sure how exactly it works, I'm fairly certain it breaks up any processes the exe generates and then injects them into the "layer" it creates underneath the desktop. This subsequently moves the application to background processes in task manager. And here lies my problem:

When I give Wallpaper Engine the exe file, it is seemingly unable to break up the processes and then do whatever else it needs to do to inject it into the layer. I know that it's possible for Wallpaper Engine to do this with an electron application, as another one developed for Wallpaper Engine (in 2017) is able to be broken up just fine. However, when looking at the files for that application I see no notable difference that would enable it to be broken up then injected while my own application cannot.

Are there any reasons, such as something new with security or updates to IPC, that could prevent a more modern Electron application from being broken up by an external program?

Comment: Had you seen this (from 2017): https://steamcommunity.com/app/431960/discussions/1/1327844097112013448/